# How to add a panel class to my frame in main class

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I am fairly new to oo, I have created a class which is most of the interface of my program, I have put it all together in a class. I then want to add my Panel class to my main class so my panels are attached to my Frame:

This is what I have tried, I am not receiving any errors, when I run my program but the panels are not displaying:

**Panel Class:**

```
  public class PanelDriver extends JPanel {
       public JPanel p1, myg;
       public PanelDriver() {

       JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
       p1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

      // Graphicsa myg = new Graphicsa();


    JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(5,20);
    txt.setText("test");
    p1.add(txt);

   }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class GraphicMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Program");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);

    PanelDriver panels = new PanelDriver();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panels);

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1,2);
}
```

Comment: The code is not even compiling!!

Comment: @Azodious it should do now, sorry!

Comment: @Azodious without `Graphicsa myg = new Graphicsa();` it does, but nothing actually happnes xD

Answer (score 0):

you need a super call (because you extend JPanel you don't need to create a new one) and a layout in you Panel class like this:

```
public class CustomerTest extends JPanel {

    public CustomerTest() {
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        txt.setText("test");
        this.add(txt);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and then in your main class use this, to set the frame visible and display the content. you have to set the layout for the frame after you created it:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Program");
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);

    CustomerTest panels = new CustomerTest();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);;
    frame.add(panels);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PanelDriver` class creates a `p1` `JPanel`, but doesn't add it to anything.

At least add it to the `PanelDriver` itself :

```
this.add(p1);
```

Note that as your code is, the frame isn't even displaying, look at the answer by @XtremeBaumer to fix that part.